# repeating-linear-gradient is not rendering evenly in safari

Tags: css, safari, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm having problems with my background in Safari.

```css
body {
  background-color: #161619;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(240, 240, 255, .1), rgba(20, 20, 30, .1) 60%), repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #222, #222, 3px, #252525 3px, #252525 6px);
}
```

All other browsers (incl. Chrome) give me a nice striped background: 
[image: a nice striped background]

But Safari (Version 11.0.1) made it soft stripes in different sizes: 
[image: soft stripes in different sizes]

So I tried prefixes – but safari doesn't use the right one. 
(I tried a colour-change)

```css
body {
  background-color: #161619;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(240, 240, 255, .1), rgba(20, 20, 30, .1) 60%), -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #222, #222, 3px, #500000 3px, #500000 6px);
  background-image: -o-radial-gradient(rgba(240, 240, 255, .1), rgba(20, 20, 30, .1) 60%), -o-repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #222, #222, 3px, #252525 3px, #252525 6px);
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(240, 240, 255, .1), rgba(20, 20, 30, .1) 60%), repeating-linear-gradient(40deg, #222, #222, 3px, #252525 3px, #252525 6px);
}
```

I've been trying a lot of stuff now. But nothing works.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Webkit seems to have issues when rendering gradients at certain degrees and with low contrast. At times, the results are completely unpredictable.

**Problem is exacerbated when these snippets are run in full screen.**

`45deg` angle gives the best results.

Heavy contrast:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
   45deg, 
   #fff, /* heavy contrast */ 
   #fff 0.5em, 
   #252525 0.5em, 
   #252525 1em)
}
```

Lower contrast:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
   45deg, 
   #111, /* heavy contrast */ 
   #111 0.5em, 
   #252525 0.5em, 
   #252525 1em)
}
```

I also noted that the results are better when using responsive units, such as `em` used above. With pixels things get even more wonky.

Very low contrast with pixel units, `40deg` angle:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
   40deg, 
   #111, 
   #111 3px, 
   #252525 3px, 
   #252525 6px)
}
```

Very low contrast with pixel units but larger size, `40deg` angle:

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
 background: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
   30deg, 
   #222, /* heavy contrast */ 
   #222 20px, 
   #252525 20px, 
   #252525 40px)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Tipps. I tried some of them before – some were new – and now I am absolutely sure, that I can't get the exact result I want via "repating-linear-gradient" in Safari. I'm going to use an image for this Browser. #sad